# referring asp.net dll to php

Tags: php, .net

I am referring a `ASP.NET` assembly in php script using DotNet class

i.e.

```
$test = new DOTNET('assemblyname','classname');
```

I am getting a fatal error while running this script.

**Fatal error:**

> Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to instantiate
>   .Net object [CreateInstance] [0x80131513] ' in C:\Program
>   Files\xampplite\htdocs\xampp\phptest.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program
>   Files\xampplite\htdocs\xampp\phptest.php(2):
>   dotnet->dotnet('EncryptDecrypt,...', 'EncryptDecrypt....') #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\Program Files\xampplite\htdocs\xampp\phptest.php on line
>   2

Any help on this?

Comment: Can you please post the full error message with full stacktrace?

Comment: Can you please also post the actual method call in your PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because either your library is not found in the GAC and not strong named  or not COMVisible.

For making COMVisible, make sure that AssemblyInfo.cs is like this:

[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

For strong names and installing it in the GAC, I found this post:

> For strongly-named NET assemblies that are registered in the GAC, you
>   can just use the assembly name e.g: $x = new DOTNET ("myAssembly",
>   "myClass");
>
> For strongly-named NET assemblies that aren't registered in the GAC,
>   you need to use the full assembly string e.g. $x = new
>   DOTNET('myAssembly, Version=X.X.X.X, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=ZZZZZZZZZZZZ', 'myClass');
>
> You can't instantiate assemblies that haven't been strongly named.
>
> "Strongly named" means that the assembly has a public key. To strongly
>   name your own classes in Visual Studio, go to the Signing tab in the
>   project properties and click the 'sign the assembly' box and choose a
>   key file name.
>
> To register an assembly in the GAC, there are various tools around to
>   do that, but the easiest method is to drag-and-drop the compiled
>   assembly into c:\windows\assembly using windows explorer (a shell
>   extension is installed by default that handles registering dragged
>   files).

Source: [PHP: DOTNET - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php)

Comment: Yes,I have tried dragging the file into GAC and also by giving the Version,PublicKeyToken.I am getting the same fatal error as mentioned above.

Comment: My PHP code:<?php
 $test = new DOTNET('assemblyname,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=2e876b965e29b68a', 'classname');
 $test->methodname("1356");
 echo $test;
?>

Comment: Maybe this is my dumbest observation here, but the assemblyname should be something like mylib.dll. I suspect that in your real project you have the exact .net library name in your PHP method call. First, I would try to call some well known method of some well known library (e.g mscorlib.dll Console.WriteLine) to see if the problem is with your PHP code or with your .NET. If the call goes through than the PHP is ok and the problem is with your .NET library

Comment: My assemblyname is also like "zzz.dll".I have tried the same code  with,                                                            <?php
 $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
 $stack->Push(".Net");
 $stack->Push("Hello ");
 echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
?>
and this works fine.

Comment: Please, create a sample project that still shows the problem and send it too me my email. My email is the same as my username and it ends with gmail.com :)